# How to use shortcode of any plugin to show it visually where i want?

Tags: plugins, posts, shortcode

I don't know much about shortcode. I have a countdown plugin with this plugin i'm displaying 'countdown timer', i can post it with shortcode E.g `[countdown event="Event with hour &amp; minutes" date="12 June" hour="18" minutes="54"]`. I tried to fetch it with `get_post_field('post_content', $post->ID)` but with this way I can not displaying the 'countdown timer' as visually, just fetch the lettering. Is it possible to show countdown plugin with shortcode where i want. Hope you can help. I really need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_post_field` alone does not render shortcodes. Try

```
echo do_shortcode( get_post_field( 'post_content', $post->ID) );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear and working answer. You saved my life:)